# MySQL split keyword with space automatically

Tags: mysql

I'm having a below table called `members`

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+--+
| id | name   | gender | state |  |
+----+--------+--------+-------+--+
| 1  | Peter  | M      | 1     |  |
+----+--------+--------+-------+--+
| 2  | Sally  | F      | 1     |  |
+----+--------+--------+-------+--+
| 3  | Martin | M      | 0     |  |
+----+--------+--------+-------+--+
```

Then, my query is

```
SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `id` = '1 3';
```

MySQL returned `| 1  | Peter  | M      | 1     |  |`.

However, I expect that it would return nothing because there should be no record with `id = '1 3'`.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: If id is an integer then your query is behaving as expected (mysql does a string to integer conversion taking the first n characters before a non integer value in the string). .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `BINARY`

```
select * from member where BINARY id = '1 3';
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!